# Calculate average of stages across sequences

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I need to compute and report the average time spent in each stage across sequences.

More details...

I have a StageTable and a DataTable. The StageTable is the master table containing the names of stages (in order) within a sequence

**StageTable**

```
Id Stage
== ======
1   Alpha
2   Bravo
3   Charlie
4   Delta
5   End
```

The DataTable contains the start times of stages. There are entities called "sequences" (which have the same correlation Id), each of which contain the four stages.

**DataTable**

```
CorrelationId   StageName   StartTime
==============  =========   =========
abc             Alpha        1pm
abc             Bravo        1.03pm          --implies that Alpha == 3min
abc             Charlie      1.07pm          --Bravo == 4min 
abc             Delta        1.10pm          --Charlie == 3min
abc             End          1.13pm
bbc             Alpha        2pm
bbc             Bravo        2.13pm          --Alpha == 13min
bbc             Charlie      2.17pm
bbc             Delta        2.21pm
bbc             End          2.25pm
```

## Output

```
StageName   DurationTotal(min)  DurationAvg(min)
=========   ==================  ================  
Alpha        16                  8
Bravo        8                   4
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need `lead()` to get the next time:

```
select t.*,
       lead(starttime) over (partition by correlationid order by starttime) as next_starttime
from t;
```

You can then get the average with something like this:

```
select stagename,
       sum(datediff(second, starttime, next_starttime) * 1.0) as sum_dur,
       avg(datediff(second, starttime, next_starttime) * 1.0) as avg_dur
from (select t.*,
             lead(starttime) over (partition by correlationid order by starttime) as next_starttime
      from t
     ) t
group by stagename;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was exactly what I was looking for.